# Rake test : NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am constantly getting this error and unable to understand the issue. As the whole stack does not have any of my code. The only hint i have is that this started happening after a git merge.

Here is the error stack please let me know if you have any clue. Thanks

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/ac
tion_controller/test_case.rb:58:in `teardown_subscriptions'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib
/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib
/active_support/callbacks.rb:263:in `call'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib
/active_support/callbacks.rb:263:in `block in simple'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib
/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `call'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib
/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block in call'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib
/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `each'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib
/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `call'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib
/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib
/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_teardown_callbacks'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib
/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib
/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:45:in `after_teardown'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/
active_record/fixtures.rb:829:in `after_teardown'
```

Comment: Can you share your failing test with us? It seems that you try to clear somehing in your teardown method (`teardown_subscriptions`) by running each on a collection, but the collection seems to be nil.

Comment: Thanks @daniel I actually wrote a empty which still fails.. I figured out that the yml fixtures are not getting loaded correctly.. Is there any way to test your fixtures in test/fixtures

Comment: @daniel-schmidt  I wrote an empty test

Comment: Yes, the test is not the problem in fact. your teardown method is the problem. I guess you have a collection there on which you call each, this isn't possible if you don't instantiate it in your test

Comment: @daniel-schmidt well you were right.. Though I thought it's not a code issue as my code was not in the stack... But the issue was one of the model validation was failing and the fixtures were not loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the model validation was failing while loading the fixtures.This validation error was not thrown and the test cases failed with the message 'NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass'